# RabbitMQ how to control how much message consumed by queue

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq

I am consuming the messages in the following way, using an inbound channel adapter configuration.

```
    @Bean
    public AmqpInboundChannelAdapter itemInboundChannelAdapter(@Qualifier(value = "errorChannel") MessageChannel errorChannel,
                                                               @Qualifier(value = "itemChannel") Queue itemQueue,
                                                               Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder objectMapperBuilder,
                                                               ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {

        final SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory);
        container.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(1);
        container.setExclusive(true);
        container.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.AUTO);
        container.setQueueNames(itemQueue.getName());

        return Amqp
                .inboundAdapter(container)
                .errorChannel(errorChannel)
                .outputChannel(itemValidateChannel())
                .messageConverter(new PackageConvertingJackson2JsonMessageConverter(objectMapperBuilder.build(), Item.class))
                .get();
    }
```

As can be seen in the screenshot, I am consuming 250 messages at a time. How can I limit this to 10s?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not consuming 250 by 250 but you're prefetching. You can use:

```java
container.setPrefetchCount(10);
```

to limit the prefetch count.